# Symfony2 - Twig extension does not exist in Twig file

Tags: symfony, service, twig

I am trying to register (read the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html)) a Twig extension and everything seems to be correct except it's not being found in the Twig file.

Getting the following error:

`The function "getPostCount" does not exist in AcmeDemoBundle:Page:index.html.twig at line 17`

**Can someone show me what I am doing wrong?**

**services.yml**

```
acme.twig.acme_extension:
    class: Acme\DemoBundle\Twig\PostExtension
    tags:
        - { name: twig. extension }
    arguments:
        em: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
```

**PostExtension.php**

```
class PostExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
private $em;

public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
{
    $this->em  = $em;
}

public function getFilters()
{
    return array(
    );
}

public function getFunctions()
{
    return array(
        'getPostCount' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this,'getPostCount')
    );
}

public function getPostCount($year, $month)
{
    return $this->$em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Post')
        ->getPostCountsByMonth($year, $month);
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'post_extension';
}
}
```

**Twig**

```
{{ getPostCount('2014', 'July') }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In services.yml:

Remove the extra space in twig.extension.

```
 tags:
    - { name: twig.extension }
```